# when I switch other language using google translate cart functionality is not working in which there is some vuejs code used

Tags: javascript, php, vue.js

**This is google translate js code:**

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
   function googleTranslateElementInit() {  new 
   google.translate.TranslateElement({pageLanguage: 'en'}, 
   'google_translate_element');}
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" 
   src="//translate.google.com/translate_a/element.js? 
   cb=googleTranslateElementInit"></script>
<div class="translate" id="google_translate_element"></div>
```

Whole site I am getting translated and also when I came to add products in cart it will store products without using google translation but when I switch to another language it is not updating cart and when I reload page it is updating; there is also some code of vueJs in cart.

**VueJs code:**

```html
<div v-if="totalPrice" v-cloak class="text-center mobile-menu add_more_btn">
   <a type="button" class="btn service-btn" style="text-transform:none" 
      onclick="closeNav()">{{ __('+Add Item') }}</a>
</div>
<div class="place_order_btn" v-if="totalPrice" v-cloak>
   <a href="/cart-checkout" class="btn service-btn">{{ __('Place Order') }}</a>
</div>
```

Furthermore, my question is that; does google translate not work in vuejs? I am not ware of vueJs please help me. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Do you see any errors in the console?

Comment: No brother, there is no error shown in console